# Simple cascade delete self referencing table with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_AuthCategories_Parent". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB",
>   table "dbo.AuthCategories",
>   column 'ParentID'.

If I try to remove everything in a table that has a self-referencing FK for a ParentID I get the error above that I need to essentially remove children first (i.e. it tries to delete a parent item that has children which breaks the FK).

```
var dc = from c in db.AuthCategories
         select c;
db.AuthCategories.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dc);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Is there a simple LINQ to SQL query that will delete everything in a table while handling cascading deletes?

- Don't want to use SQL server side solution such as Triggers or ON DELETE CASCADE
- Need to use LINQ to SQL, not EF
- Would like it to be as simple as possible, one-liner if possible

Here's the table structure:

```
[Table(Name = "AuthCategories")]
public class AuthCategory
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column]
    private int? ParentID { get; set; }
    private EntityRef<AuthCategory> parent;
    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, ThisKey = "ParentID")]
    public AuthCategory Parent
    {
        get { return parent.Entity; }
        set { parent.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, coffee kicked in, this works:

Add a Children IEnumerable to the class:

```
private EntitySet<AuthCategory> children = new EntitySet<AuthCategory>();
[Association(Storage = "children", OtherKey = "ParentID")]
public IEnumerable<AuthCategory> AuthCatChildren
{
    get { return children; }
}
public IEnumerable<AuthCategory> Children
{
    get { return (from x in AuthCatChildren select x).AsEnumerable(); }
}
```

And now you can delete children first through a `while` loop:

```
// Loop, Deleting all rows with no children (which would delete childless parents and nested grandchild/children)
int loop = 1;
while (loop > 0)
{
    var dbList = from c in db.AuthCategories.ToList()
                    where c.Children.Count() == 0
                    select c;
    loop = dbList.Count();
    db.AuthCategories.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dbList);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: L2S does not have native support for self-referencing cascade deletes - out of curiosity, why do you not want to use ON_DELETE_CASCADE? How will that delete code perform when you have a million rows in your table?

Comment: Well, you *can* use `ON_DELETE_CASCADE` but this loop gives a bit more control / can be expanded to delete only certain parent/children instead of forcefully blowing away everything.

Comment: fair enough, although I still do think that you will hit a wall as soon as you go over a few hundred rows!